# The best approach to handle dirty data in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently studying the program design of asp.Net Core Web API but I have no any ideas on the following issues.

Assuming that there is a payment function, which has to check the account balance in Db before calling the payment gateway and update the account balance after that. How do I make sure there is no dirty data and only 1 SQL statement will be executed at the same time?

Comment: One word: Transaction.

Comment: Do you have a single user or multi-user database?  With a multiuser data base you need to lock the account so nobody else accesses the account between the time the check is performed and the time the transaction is performed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start new transaction for payment operation.

```
private static void DoPayment(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction;

        // Start a local transaction.
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

        // Must assign both transaction object and connection
        // to Command object for a pending local transaction
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try
        {
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (101, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Attempt to commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

            // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                // a closed connection.
                Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

detail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction